# Why input[type="checkbox"]:checked method does not work on body tag and is there any work around?

Tags: html, css

We often use a hidden checkbox in html to toogle between css properties and styling but this method isn't working with body tag in the following example

**HTML**

```
<html>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<body>
 ...
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked~body{
background:grey;
}
```

this code dosen't work as intended.So I want to know why this happens and is there any work around for this?

Thanks everyone for the replies

Comment: it is an invalid markup. input elements should be inside body, not outside. _We often use a hidden checkbox in html to toogle between css properties and styling_ this is imho not a good approach

Comment: You can't select things that are above a given element in the DOM, you can only select those below it.

Comment: Okay, that's why the input element was automatically inserted into the body tag after rendering.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can use another `div` to "simulate" the body

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.container {
  background: grey;
}

.container {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <div class="container">

  </div>
  ...
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, this is just works but as it only applies to the element so nothing changes in DOM actually, so in my example (background property) it works fine but will it work if we try to manupulate other properties like height,width of the DOM ?

Comment: Yeah you will have to get all your content in that container.